# grails javax.websocket issues

Tags: grails, websocket

Grails 2.3.7 - Java 1.7

I have seen the following example used in core java and working as a demo, trying to achieve the same in Grails, I know there are a few plugins around websockets but I was trying to figure this out on my own :

Controller 1

```
package chat

class TestController {

    def index() { }
}
```

index.gsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'admin.label', default: 'Admin')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName,BAH,BAH]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>  
    <form>
    <input id="textMessage" type="text">
    <input type="button" value="send" onClick="sendMessage();">
    </form>
    <br>
    <textarea id="messagesTextarea" rows="10" cols="50">
    </textarea>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var webSocket=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/chat/testing");
        var messagesTextarea=document.getElementById("messagesTextarea");
        var textMessage=document.getElementById("textMessage");
        webSocket.onopen=function(message) {processOpen(message);};
        webSocket.onmessage=function(message) {processMessage(message);};
        webSocket.onclose=function(message) {processClose(message);};
        webSocket.onerror=function(message) {processError(message);};
        function processOpen(message) {
            messagesTextarea.value +=" Server Connect.... "+"\n";
        }
        function processMessage(message) {
            messagesTextarea.value +=" Receive from Server ===> "+ message.data +"\n";
        }
        function sendMessage() {
            if (textMssage.value!="close") {
                webSocket.send(textMessage.value);
                messagesTextarea.value +=" Send to Server ===> "+ textMessage.value +"\n";
                textMessage.value="";
            }else {
                websocket.close();
            }   
        }
        function processClose(message) {
            webSocket.send("Client disconnected......");
            messagesTextarea.value +="Server Disconnected... "+"\n";
        }
        function processError(message) {
            messagesTextarea.value +=" Error.... \n";
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Controller 2:

```
package chat

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/testing")
class TestingController  {

    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen() {
        System.out.println("Client is now connected.");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage(String message) {

        System.out.println("Client sent: " + message);
        String replyMessage = "echo "+message;
        System.out.println("Send to Client: " + replyMessage);
        return replyMessage;
    }

    @OnClose
    public void handeClose() {
        System.out.println("Client is now disconnected.");
    }

    @OnError
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

With this as is when I run app

I get the following error in chrome:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/chat/testing' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 index:37
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

and in textArea

```
Error.... 
Server Disconnected...
```

on ggts console I see:

```
Client sent: null
Send to Client: echo null
```

Initially I attempted controller this way:

```
package chat


class TestingController extends TestingEndpoint  {

}
```

and in src/java/chat

```
package chat;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;


@ServerEndpoint("/testing")
class TestingEndpoint  {

    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen() { 
        System.out.println("Client is now connected.");
    }
    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage(String message) {

        System.out.println("Client sent: " + message);
        String replyMessage = "echo "+message;
        System.out.println("Send to Client: " + replyMessage);
        return replyMessage;
    }
    @OnClose
    public void handeClose() { 
        System.out.println("Client is now disconnected.");
    }
    @OnError
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This method produced same result except nothing in ggts console

Wondering if anyone has got javax.websocket to work in Grails..

Answer (score 1):

ok got it working - was not that bad after all

here is the fix:

1. a few typos in the gsp :

index.gsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'admin.label', default: 'Admin')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName,BAH,BAH]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>  
    <form>
    <input id="textMessage" type="text">
    <input type="button" value="send" onClick="sendMessage();">
    </form>
    <br>
    <textarea id="messagesTextarea" rows="10" cols="50">
    </textarea>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var webSocket=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/chat/annotated");
        var messagesTextarea=document.getElementById("messagesTextarea");
        webSocket.onopen=function(message) {processOpen(message);};
        webSocket.onmessage=function(message) {processMessage(message);};
        webSocket.onclose=function(message) {processClose(message);};
        webSocket.onerror=function(message) {processError(message);};
        function processOpen(message) {
            messagesTextarea.value +=" Server Connect.... "+"\n";
        }
        function processMessage(message) {
            messagesTextarea.value +=" Receive from Server ===> "+ message.data +"\n";
        }
        function sendMessage() {

            if (textMessage.value!="close") {
                webSocket.send(textMessage.value);
                messagesTextarea.value +=" Send to Server ===> "+ textMessage.value +"\n";
                textMessage.value="";
            }else {
                websocket.close();
            }   
        }
        function processClose(message) {
            webSocket.send("Client disconnected......");
            messagesTextarea.value +="Server Disconnected... "+"\n";
        }
        function processError(message) {
            messagesTextarea.value +=" Error.... \n";
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now the actual fix for the end point, I stumbled across it from here:
https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.7/index/deployment.html
Example 3.2. Deployment of Annotated Endpoint Using ServerContainer

So the fix was to add a src/java/MyServletContextListenerAnnotated.java

```
package chat;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.websocket.DeploymentException;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;



@WebListener
@ServerEndpoint("/annotated")
public class MyServletContextListenerAnnotated implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        final ServerContainer serverContainer = (ServerContainer) servletContextEvent.getServletContext()
                                                    .getAttribute("javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer");

        try {
            serverContainer.addEndpoint(MyServletContextListenerAnnotated.class);
        } catch (DeploymentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   /* @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message) {
        return message;
    }
*/
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    }
    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen() { 
        System.out.println("Client is now connected.");
    }
    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage(String message) {

        System.out.println("Client sent: " + message);
        String replyMessage = "echo "+message;
        System.out.println("Send to Client: " + replyMessage);
        return replyMessage;
    }
    @OnClose
    public void handeClose() { 
        System.out.println("Client is now disconnected.");
    }
    @OnError
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Since the endpoint in gsp already updated to use new endpoint the final touch was to add _Events.groovy to scripts:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

eventWebXmlEnd = {String tmpfile ->
    def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(webXmlFile)
    root.appendNode {
       'listener' {
           'listener-class' (
               'chat.MyServletContextListenerAnnotated'
           )
        }
    }

    webXmlFile.text = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
        mkp.declareNamespace(
                "": "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee")
        mkp.yield(root)
    }
}
```

and booom there it is - server connected client send blah

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-websocket-example project uploaded here - will ammend with the chat example provided on the videos etc